# How use react-loadble for code spitting with ssr?

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

After breaking, I get empty chunks and a bundle array.

I completely do everything as written in the documentation.

To get started, wrapping a component

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const LoadableAbout = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./About'),
    loading() {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
});

export default LoadableAbout;
```

I import, so

```
// About it's folder
import About from "./containers/About";
```

server.js. I use preloadReady because use hydrate.

```
let port = process.env.npm_package_config_port;

Loadable.preloadReady().then(() => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("server run on port "+port);
    });
});
```

```
<Loadable.Capture report={moduleName => modules.push(moduleName)}>
  <AppMain />
</Loadable.Capture>
```

```
${bundles.map(bundle => {
    return `<script src="/${bundle.file}"></script>`
}).join('\n')}
<script src="/client.js"></script>
```

Comment: why not just use `React.lazy`

Comment: I see text "Loading", but modules array is empty

Comment: @Rikin React.lazy and Suspense are not yet available for server-side rendering.

Comment: Ok Thanks, did not know that, good to know, it probably may be available in future, I guess you can just bump the react version if you have that liberty instead of relying on a package.

Comment: @Rikin Why did you ask about react version ?

Comment: Nevermind it is actually recommended by React for SSR in their docs